# How do I look up a revision's delta/diff using svn's http-based browser?

Tags: svn, diff, revision

I'm working on a project to link an issue tacker to our source control system.

I've found that you can lookup a specific revision in the svn web browser with this:

`https://svn-repo/!svn/bc/100/`

or

`https://svn-repo/?p=100`

or

`https://svn-repo/?r=100`

But this shows you the entire repository structure at that revision.  The ultimate objective is to be able to create a link to a URL a browser can click on to see the changes a revision made.  Is this possible?  I can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I didn't know, that we can back-time in default repo-browser, Thank you for hint
2. You *can* see *single-file* in any revision, just add filename in URL, examples of single file: [R28](http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.en.txt?p=28)  vs  [Trunk](http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.en.txt)
3. For diffs, I'm afraid, you have to use some additional web-frontend ([WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) isn't bad choice)